# JS Target Respective Value in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, dom

I have a for loop which is responsible for opening a custom modal. The opening button is defined as multiple elements with the class of `.col-sm-4`

Here are the code:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the opening trigger
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-4');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  // Open modal by clicking the order display
  btn[i].onclick = function(event) {

    // Check to see if target is the parent element
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') {

      modal.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-4');
      var idDIVOrderParent = btn[0].id;
      // Having trouble grabbing the correct ID
      console.log('The order ID is ' + idDIVOrderParent);

      // extract orderId9999 from string like parentOrderId9999
      var idDIVOrder = 'o' + idDIVOrderParent.substr(7);
      console.log('The modal is currently displaying ' + idDIVOrder);

      document.getElementById(idDIVOrder).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      // console.log('Child element clicked!');
    }
  }
}
```

Where it says `var idDIVOrderParent = btn[0].id` is where I'm having difficulties. How can I grab the ID of the correct `.col-sm-4` which triggered the modal?

Comment: You can access the button that was clicked through `event.target`.

Comment: You can use `event.currentTarget.id` instead of `btn[0]` or create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-4');` <-- that line does nothing

Comment: Thanks @Alex and @Titus! Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.

Comment: I have an additional question, if I want to close the modal with an X button and by clicking outside of the modal display, how can I apply `display: none` to the same `.col-sm-4`?  

Here are the [code for closing the modal](https://jsfiddle.net/wallacelin/4eazkcvd/). Sorry for the incomplete snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-4');

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function(event) {

    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') {
      modal.style.display = 'block';

      let idDIVOrderParent = btn[i].id;
      console.log('The order ID is ' + idDIVOrderParent);

      let idDIVOrder = 'o' + idDIVOrderParent.substr(7);
      modal.textContent = idDIVOrder;
      console.log('The modal is currently displaying ' + idDIVOrder);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myModal {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentOrderId9999" class="col-sm-4">btn1</div>
<div id="parentOrderId1111" class="col-sm-4">btn2</div>
<div id="parentOrderId2222" class="col-sm-4">btn3</div>
<div id="parentOrderId3333" class="col-sm-4">btn4</div>

<div id="myModal"></div>
```